# How to fix this import pandas problem in M1 Mac?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, apple-m1, pyenv

I bought Mac M1, and now setting up my python environment.

- I installed Rosetta 2, and set my Terminal as Rosetta 2
- I installed pyenv with brew
- installed Sqlite3 with brew
- installed python 3.9.4 with pyenv (set as global)
- installed visual studio code with brew
- and finally I installed pandas with "pip install pandas" in my Terminal.

Now I opened a jypyter notebook file in VS Code, and trying to import pandas as pd,
then it threw in this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/r5/wq0wq8mx0d56rbrbs38jt94w0000gn/T/ipykernel_10428/1362986570.py in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     20 
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat import (
     23     np_version_under1p18 as _np_version_under1p18,
     24     is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev,

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py in <module>
     13 
     14 from pandas._typing import F
---> 15 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
     16     is_numpy_dev,
     17     np_array_datetime64_compat,

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from pandas.util.version import Version
      8 
      9 # numpy versioning

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa
      2     Appender,
      3     Substitution,
      4     cache_readonly,
      5 )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in <module>
     12 import warnings
     13 
---> 14 from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa
     15 from pandas._typing import F
     16 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13 from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
     14 from pandas._libs.tslibs import (
     15     NaT,

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

What should I do to fix it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reinstalling pandas after removing it?

Comment: I "pip uninstall pandas", I confirmed it is deleted with "pip list".  Then I "pip install pandas" again in my arm64 Terminal. But it says "Requirement already satisfied.. Successfully installed pandas-1.3.0". And when I "import pandas as pd" in VScode again, the same error pops up...

Comment: it says "Using cached pandas-1.3.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl" how can I clear the cache?

Comment: try `pip cache purge`

Comment: thank you hd1, I purged it with "pip cache purge", then install with arm64 Terminal, now it gives me this error like message "/Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:124: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)" would you please tell me how to fix this lzma?

Comment: run `brew install xz` . After this, install python to avoid your lzma compression error

Comment: when you say install python, do I use pyenv to install? do I have to uninstall the 3.9.4 I am having in pyenv?

Comment: Just recreating your venv should do the trick, @yts61.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VSCode is native (ARM code), so it also starts a native jupyter... Try installing a native pandas version using a non Rosetta 2 terminal.

Comment: Thank you for dropping by, I tried using pip install pandas in the arm64 Terminal, however it says: Requirement already satisfied: pandas