# How to fix this import matplotlib problem in M1 Mac?

Tags: python, matplotlib, apple-m1, pyenv

I bought Mac M1, and now setting up my python environment.

- I installed Rosetta 2, and set my Terminal as Rosetta 2
- I installed pyenv with brew
- installed Sqlite3 with brew
- installed python 3.9.4 with pyenv (set as global)
- installed visual studio code with brew
- installed pandas with pip in Terminal(arm64) (problem solved, thank you [hd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9779999/yts61))

Now I am trying to import matplotlib after "pip install matplotlib" in  Terminal(arm64), it shows this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/r5/wq0wq8mx0d56rbrbs38jt94w0000gn/T/ipykernel_54247/646680447.py in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>
    155 
    156 
--> 157 _check_versions()
    158 
    159 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _check_versions()
    149             ("pyparsing", "2.2.1"),
    150     ]:
--> 151         module = importlib.import_module(modname)
    152         if LooseVersion(module.__version__) < minver:
    153             raise ImportError("Matplotlib requires {}>={}; you have {}"

~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    125                 break
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 
    129 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Users/yeung/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kiwisolver.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

While it says it is wrong architecture, I tried the solution for [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68369558/how-to-fix-this-import-pandas-problem-in-m1-mac/68369582?noredirect=1#comment120858779_68369582) here. It's basically pip uninstall it, and then make sure it is installed with my arm64 Terminal. I uninstalled and purged the cache, then "pip installed" with my arm64 Terminal, but still this error.

Any clue for that? Again, I am using Visual Studio Code and Jupyter notebook .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these codes, they work for me. As you are using pyenv, you can just `pyenv uninstall 3.9.4`to clear the instance, and then reinstall `pyenv install 3.9.4` again. After that, try the codes below.

```
python -m pip install cython   
python -m pip install --no-binary :all: --no-use-pep517 numpy
brew install libjpeg
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

The origin of the codes come from here: https://flutterq.com/pip-install-matplotlib-fails-on-m1-mac/

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly that very frustrating error on my brand new MacBook Pro M1.

After a long time struggling I found out that I had to uninstall ALL installed pip packages.

```
pip3 freeze | xargs pip3 uninstall -y
```

And then only, I could peacefully reinstall and import all my favourites packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling, and then reinstalling the package that gives the error. In your case it was 'kiwisolver'. In my case it was psutil. So the following worked for me:

```
pip uninstall psutil
pip install psutil
```

and just replace psutil with 'whatever package is giving the error'.